# function corr(double precision, double precision) does not exist -- PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, error-handling

Hi when I run simple correlation query in PostgreSQL

```
select 
    corr(m07_selling_price_total_usd, m12_amount_of_commission_earned_usd)
from order;
```

I get following error:

`ERROR:  function corr(double precision, double precision) does not exist`

Any ideas about how to solve it? Both variables are double precision so according to documentation (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-aggregate.html) it should work.

Comment: Can you run a `select version();` and a `show search_path;` ?

Comment: Tx Clement, i've checked and it's indeed 8.02 (Redshift on AWS) and after further research it's really the case - they don't support corr(). It's really version issue as you suggest. Many thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

As `corr` exists since PostgreSQL 8.2, I'll guess that you have a bad [`search_path`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/runtime-config-client.html) configuration.

This configuration tells PostgreSQL where to look when you use non-schema-prefixed objects.

It should work if you specify the schema explicitly (I used `\df corr` to find that this function is located in `pg_catalog`)

```
select 
    pg_catalog.corr(m07_selling_price_total_usd, m12_amount_of_commission_earned_usd)
from "order";
```